# Pop open a mail window that has HTML formatting, C#

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I currently have a text box in a program where the user can input text and format it in HTML (  tags around bold text, etc).

I was using MAPI32.DLL to open an email window in Outlook with this text, but it seems like MAPI is not a good interface for HTML, as it left the raw HTML in there, displaying the actual <> tags.

So, I am currently pursuing alternative ways to pop open an email window, with the HTML text formatted.  I have read suggestions of using SMTP, but will that still allow me to pop open the email window with the user's email program, or is it going to send the email directly?  I would prefer the former, with the email popping open in the user's email client.

Thanks.

Comment: This may help: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-2968448.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that the simplest solution would to be to use one of the many WYSIWYG HTML text editors out there to display/edit the email, then use SMTP to send it.

Here is an editor that I have used in the past that is pretty simple:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/editor_in_windows_forms.aspx

Comment: However, having it open in Outlook would be useful because then you could set up your contacts more easily, so that is what I would prefer.  I have something similar to what you showed before, where it is WYSIWYG, but then MAPI displays the HTML formatting tags when opening in outlook.

Comment: The Office SDK contains an API to interface with Outlook - could you use this to obtain the user's contacts?